# VTK python on mac does not catch the keyboard events

Tags: python, macos, vtk

I have the following question. I have compiled the latest VTK under Mac Os X 10.6, and I am using Python bindings. The python distribution I use is the Enthought Python Distribution (EPD). Everything works quite well, however there is a difference in behaviour of the same program on Mac and on Linux with respect to keyboard event. It seems, that I miss some very important point. 
The part of the code is as follows

```
    vtkrenderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    vtkrenderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    vtkrenderWindow.SetSize(800, 600)
    vtkrenderWindow.AddRenderer(vtkrenderer)
    vtkrenderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    vtkrenderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(vtkrenderWindow)
    vtkrenderWindow.Render()
    vtkrenderer.ResetCamera()
    vtkrenderWindowInteractor.GetRenderWindow().AddObserver('CharEvent', self.show_update)
    vtkrenderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

The function `self.show_update` has the following form:

```
def show_update(self, renderer, event):
    if renderer.GetKeyCode() == ' ':
        self.update(renderer, event)
        print 'ready'
        #Do computations here
        renderer.Render()
```

However, the spacebar is working only in the terminal, where I launch the program (using `python test_particles.py` but is completely ignored in the Cocoa window.

In Linux everything works as expected (keyboards are working fine).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try launching the program with `pythonw`:

```
pythonw test_particles.py
```

This worked for me under OS X 10.10.2 using the Anaconda Scientific Python Distribution.